# Oracle APEX 5.1.2: Feedback Region

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a client who use the built in feedback system to get his notes, but suddenly when I tries to go to the feedback I got the error as described in the image below.
I tried to delete cookies in the system and nothing happens, is there any solutions.
Regards

[image: Region Error]

Comment: Enable debugging, run the page; once it fails, view debug info - it should tell you what caused the error.

Comment: i cannot enable debugging in this page, there is no option in the page to do it

Comment: Debugging is at the bottom of the page, in the "developer's toolbar" (black coloured with white letters on it, contains "Home", "Application xxx", "Edit page yyy", ... "**Debug**", ...).

Comment: I'm in the Team Development section --> Feedback, There is no developer toolbar in the APEX internal pages!!

Comment: Sounds like an APEX bug. Have you raised this on OTN (https://community.oracle.com/community/technology_network_community/database/developer-tools/application_express)? If it's urgent, raise an SR with Oracle Support.

Comment: Absolutely, but no one answered, I think I'll go to the office hours on asktom.com